# Upload archive with a common button

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have that button and i need to open the upload dialog box, the same at 'filefield', but i don't want to simulate a click, i want to really open the dialog from my button, there's a way?

```
{
            xtype: 'panel',
            cls: 'sharedev-floatingbutton sharedev-overflow--visible sharedev-background--none',
            autoShow: true,
            floating: true,
            shadow: false,
            padding: '16 24',

        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'center'
        },

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                hidden: true,
                cls: 'sharedev-floatingbutton-contexts sharedev-overflow--visible',
                name: 'actions',
                items: [],
            }, {
                xtype: 'sharedev-floatingbutton-action',
                name: 'fab',
                margin: 8,
                cls: 'large',
                iconCls: 'icon-menu sharedev-white',
                scope: this,
                handler: this.onFabClick
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Your post looks completely incomprehensible to me. Please improve it with exact info what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to upload an archive by clicking a button what i created.

Comment: I voted to close this question as too broad. You may find information here: [ExtJS File Upload example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/file-upload.html)

Comment: This not solve the problem because the button not extend Ext.form.field.File, is a common button, and i need he do the same of  Ext.form.field.File do.